# OpenGL float[][] not working?

Tags: opengl

I have a float[][] array in my terrainFragmentShader to load render the biomes, however the code simply does not work. No errors are being cast and when I remove the code `biomeMap[int(pass_textureCoordinates.x)][int(pass_textureCoordinates.y)]` by either deleting that section or manually setting it, it loads the appropriate texture.

```
vec4 textureColour = texture(backgroundTexture, pass_textureCoordinates);

float c = biomeMap[int(pass_textureCoordinates.x)][int(pass_textureCoordinates.y)];

if(c < 0)
    textureColour = texture(sandTexture, pass_textureCoordinates);
else if(c < 32)
    textureColour = texture(stoneTexture, pass_textureCoordinates);
```

All three textures load just fine and are rendered when not using this method and the biomes are being properly loaded and initialized.

Loading:

```
public void loadBiomes(float[][] biomeMap) {
    for(int x = 0; x < Terrain.VERTEX_COUNT; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < Terrain.VERTEX_COUNT; y++) {
            super.loadFloat(location_biomeMap[x][y], biomeMap[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Initializing:

```
    location_biomeMap = new int[Terrain.VERTEX_COUNT][Terrain.VERTEX_COUNT];
    for(int x = 0; x < Terrain.VERTEX_COUNT; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < Terrain.VERTEX_COUNT; y++) {
            location_biomeMap[x][y] = super.getUniformLocation("biomeMap[" + x + "][" + y + "]");
        }
    }
```

And finally here is the entire terrainFragmentShader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoordinates;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;
in int biomeSize;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D backgroundTexture;
uniform sampler2D sandTexture;
uniform sampler2D stoneTexture;

uniform vec3 lightColour;
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;

uniform float biomeMap[128][128];

uniform float offsetX;
uniform float offsetZ;

const int levels = 32;

void main(void){

    vec4 textureColour = texture(backgroundTexture, pass_textureCoordinates);

    float c = biomeMap[int(pass_textureCoordinates.x)][int(pass_textureCoordinates.y)];

    if(c < 0)
        textureColour = texture(sandTexture, pass_textureCoordinates);
    else if(c < 32)
        textureColour = texture(stoneTexture, pass_textureCoordinates);

    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDotl = dot(unitNormal,unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDotl, 0.25);

    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);

    vec3 totalDiffuse = brightness * lightColour;

    out_Color = vec4(totalDiffuse,1.0) * textureColour;

}
```

Why isn't the biome not loading? Is it an issue in me not getting the appropriate `[x][y]` from the `pass_textureCoordinates`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multidimensional arrays in GLSL you need either one of two requirements:

- Support the extension GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays or
- Use GLSL version 430 (in which the mentioned extension became core)

Comment: I changed the core version 430, however nothing noticeable changed. Could you elaborate on how to support the extension?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to support it, if it is supported by your driver you can just enable it. Try #extension GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays: enable

Comment: Or require it, this is basically the same as enabling but throws an error if it is unsupported #extension GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays:require

Comment: Also, did you also change the version tag in your shader to #version 430 core? Because it needs this to compile against this version, not just the context version

Comment: I set the version to 430 in both the vertex and fragment shader and set the extension to be required, however it is still not working.

Comment: @TheGamerPlayz in the case that it isn't supported, you could just emulate the behavior of 2D arrays by [using a traditional array and mapping your access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151084/map-a-2d-array-onto-a-1d-array-c)

Comment: If you don't get an error with all of that then it looks like as it is supported, the error must lie elsewhere then. I would suggest a flat multidim array too. (what Matt Jens Jensen already did)

Comment: I created a flat multidim array and it works pretty well. It took a bit to understand it but I finally realized how to worked. Instead of biome[x][y], you would use biome[x*MAX+y] where MAX is the highest possible number for either x or y.

Comment: Right. It's much nicer for uploading anyways.